# Spring mixed XML/annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

We inherited an Web application. This application use an API which can be launched by command line.
Both are Spring architecture.

Unfortunately, API is annotation configuration and Web application is mixed one.

The Web aplication has an applicationContext which import the applicationContext of the API and has component scan.
Then there is a servlet configuration with full XML. This configuration was made with a old Spring version (2.5) and old controllers.

A controller is defined with a property which references an implementation service. Of course, the service is an annotation service (with a scope prototype) which has a DAO property (@Autowired).
In this controller, a classic private property defined on interface and a setter are implemented.

Our problem is the following : the service is properly instanciated in Controller but not the DAO into the service.

Any idea ?

---

[edit] Configuration files :

applicationContext.xml

```
<import resource="classpath*:/xxxApplicationContext.xml"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx.api"/>
...
```

xxxApplicationContext

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
...
```

xxx-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="theController" class="xxx.xxx.controller.XxxController">
    <property name="sessionForm">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    ...
    <property name="xxxService" ref="xxxServiceImpl"/>
</bean>
```

XxxController

```
public class XxxController extends SimpleFormController implements Validator {

    private xxxService xxxService;

    public void setXxxService(XxxService xxxService) {
        this.xxxService = xxxService;
    }
}
```

xxxServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class XxxServiceImpl implements XxxService {
    @Autowired
    private XxxDao xxxDao;
...
}
```

Comment: Ehrm... *properly instantiated in Controller*... You shouldn't be creating instances yourself... Also without `<context:annotation-config />` (or not having a `<context:component-scan />` ) no auto wiring will be done, you will have to instruct the application context to use that.

Comment: Can you provide the code as well to understand the problem better ? Current issue is the application is not able to instantiate DAO as it is Autowired, where service class instantialtion is hard coded inside controller ? am I right ?

Comment: Sorry, I could not copy/paste the code. But here we go.